# Are PUT and DELETE HTTP methods indispensable just because of their idempotency property?

Tags: rest, http

I have a REST API and I want to handle all HTTP requests via POST request.

Is there any performance or other kind of issue in using just POST to perform all CRUD operations requested by a user, which sends a JSON containing some data and the operation to be performed?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the HTML used in the Web only supports `GET` and `POST` and this is more or less the reference implementation of a REST architecture.

So, while this is possible I wouldn't advocate for something like that as the idempotency property of `PUT` and `DELETE` provide some other benefits in case of network issues where a client can automatically resend the request regardless whether the initial request, whose response might have just got lost mid-way, actually performed its task or not. The result should always be an updated/created resource or a removed URI mapping to the actual resource (or even a removal of the actual resource) as `DELETE` technically just removes the URI mapping.

In regards to put some operations in the payload, it depends. This actually sounds very RPCy to me, similar to SOAP i.e. If the operation however is defined by a well-defined media-type, like in the [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) case, I guess this is not wrong. Similar to the Web, however, a server should use some resource that is able to teach a client on how to build up a request, like HTML does with [forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html). This will not only teach the client on what fields the server supports for the target resource but also where to send the request to as well as the media-type and HTTP operation to use, which might be fixed to `POST` as in the HTML case.